# Expected value for discrete variable in tree

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

Assume the following scenario tree that has 7 nodes: Node1,...,Node7, with each node containing the value of the discrete random variable X. So for example x_1=1, x_2=2.   [image]
The probability of going from one node to its child is 50%. For example probability of going from Node2 to Node4 is 50%, and so is to go from Node1 to Node3.

In this figure we can see that: prob(X=1)=1, prob(x=2)=prob(X=3)=0.5, prob(X=4) = ... prob(X=7)=0.5*0.5.
So we can see that prob(X=2)+ prob(X=3)=1, and prob(X=4)+...+prob(X=7)=1.

Is it correct to say that
$$
 E[X] = ( prob(X=1)\bullet 1 + prob(X=2)\bullet 2 +... +prob(X=7)\bullet 7)/(prob(X=1)+...+prob(X=7))  ?
$$

Or the correct is the following: 
$$
 E[X] = ( prob(X=1)\bullet 1 + prob(X=2)\bullet 2 +... +prob(X=7)\bullet 7)  ?
$$

Comment: Probabilities should sum to one.

Comment: The tree has 3 stages. Stage1 has node1. Stage2 has node2 and node3. Stage3 has nodes 4,5,6,7. At each stage, the probabilities sum to 1.

Comment: And you define $X$ as...? Because here, your question clearly states $X$ can take all values from $1$ to $7$ with the "probabilities" you wrote, and that definitely does not sum to one. Hence, are not probabilities.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Here X is the annual salary that a wealthy person gets (in millions). So X=1 (first node) is the salary he gets in 2016. Then, in 2017, the person will get either X=2 or X=3 million dollars as his annual salary. Then, in 2018, the person will get X=4 or X=5 or X=6 or X=7 million dollars.

Comment: Should I better use three different variables rather than X? So I better use K, L , M  where K=1, L=2 or 3 and M=4 or 5 or 6 or 7 ?

Comment: I'm still unclear on what the expectation you want to compute, then. The expected salary (average over all $3$ years)? Or the expected salary at the end (in 2018)? (and yes, different letters may help then)

Comment: Yes, I want to compute the expected salary over all 3 years. So it is
$$
 E[ K + L + M ] = E[K ] + E[L] + E[M] 
$$
where 
$$
E[K] = prob(X=1)*1 
E[L] = prob(X=2)*2 + prob(X=3)*3
E[M] = prob(X=4)*4 + ... + prob(X=7)*7
$$
Or the correct is to say 
$$
[ E[K ] + E[L] + E[M] ]/ [prob(X=1)+...+prob(X=7)] 
$$
?

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[K] = 1\cdot \mathbb{P}\{K=1\} = 1\cdot 1 = 1$. $\mathbb{E}[L] = 2\cdot \mathbb{P}\{L=2\} + 3\cdot \mathbb{P}\{L=3\} = 2\cdot \frac{1}{2}+ 3 \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{5}{2}$. Etc. for $M$.

Comment: Thank you Clement. So the total expected salary over all 3 years will be 
E[K] + E[L]  + E[M] ?

Comment: The expectation of the sum of salaries will be that, yes (expectation of the "total salary over 3 years").